# Deserializing Json from iTunes store into C# object

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, app-store

I have the following Json returned from iTunes (I have replaced some details for privacy such as username and review content)

```
{"feed":{"author":{"name":{"label":"iTunes Store"}, "uri":{"label":"http://www.apple.com/uk/itunes/"}}, "entry":[
{"author":{"uri":{"label":"https://itunes.apple.com/gb/reviews/ID"}, "name":{"label":"Username"}, "label":""}, "im:version":{"label":"3.51"}, "im:rating":{"label":"4"}, "id":{"label":"12345"}, "title":{"label":"Review title"}, "content":{"label":"Review contents", "attributes":{"type":"text"}}, "link":{"attributes":{"rel":"related", "href":"https://itunes.apple.com/gb/review?reviewid"}}, "im:voteSum":{"label":"0"}, "im:contentType":{"attributes":{"term":"Application", "label":"Application"}}, "im:voteCount":{"label":"0"}}, 

// more entries ...
```

I want to deserialize this into a class. I only need the Review Title, Review contents, and the "im:rating" (which is the number of stars). However, I'm struggling due to the nested Json and the use of keys of how to extract this data. So far I have created a class ready to deserialize, and I have `AppStoreData appStoreData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppStoreData>(stringResult);` to deserialize it

```
public class AppStoreData {

}
```

My problem is that I don't know what to put inside the class to get the info I need from the Json. I have tried things such as:

`public string title {get; set;}`
`public string content {get; set;}` 
`public string imrating {get; set;}`

However this doesn't work. I also think `im:rating` is an invalid name in C#.

Can anyone please help? Thank you

Comment: There is a feature in Visual Studio that allows you to paste JSON as a class structure. 1. Copy the full json to your clipboard 2. Open Visual Studio class and click Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes 3. Remove the extra properties that you don't need.

Comment: Just create your class [here](http://json2csharp.com/) from your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around the issue with im:rating you can use a JsonProperty attribute

```
    [JsonProperty("im:rating")]
    public Id ImRating { get; set; }
```

The issue with converting things like Label to string property is that it's not a string but an object in the input file.
You need something like

```
     [JsonProperty("title")]
     public Id Title { get; set; }
```

where Id is a class

```
public class Id
{
    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Or write a deserializer that converts it to string for you.

I would suggest trying out one of many free code generators like https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp or http://json2csharp.com/ to get a headstart and edit everything to your liking afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Homulvas however when trying to get this data e.g. the Title, it is not managing to access it. I am calling it with ` resultData.Title = appStoreData.Title.Label;` but the value is null?

Comment: The code generated with quicktype and converted to .net core 3 works flawlessly
https://gist.github.com/Homulvas/34a87ca0a7b7d4027f74b3c7e9e30616
https://gist.github.com/Homulvas/a70a6cdffb8a96b67962a69529e06307
You should be calling appStoreData.Feed.Entry[0].Title.Label if you're deserialising the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert the json to c# model and change the invalid attributes by adding `JsonProperty`

```
public class Name
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}
public class Uri
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Uri uri { get; set; }
}

public class Uri2
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Name2
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Author2
{
    public Uri2 uri { get; set; }
    public Name2 name { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class ImVersion
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class ImRating
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes2
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public Attributes2 attributes { get; set; }
}

public class ImVoteSum
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes3
{
    public string term { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class ImContentType
{
    public Attributes3 attributes { get; set; }
}

public class ImVoteCount
{
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public Author2 author { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "im:version")]
    public ImVersion imversion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "im:rating")]
    public ImRating imrating { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Title title { get; set; }
    public Content content { get; set; }
    public Link link { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "im:voteSum")]
    public ImVoteSum imvoteSum { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "im:contentType")]
    public ImContentType imcontentType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "im:voteCount")]
    public ImVoteCount imvoteCount { get; set; }
}

public class Feed
{
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject5
{
    public Feed feed { get; set; }
}
```

Once the model is ready you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert the JSON to c# object

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath))  { 
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    var newEmps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject5>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(newEmps.feed.entry[0].imvoteCount.label);
}
```